# Comparing first character in char* line?

Tags: c

I want to check if a line begins with the charatcer "#". My current code gives me a segmenation fault when I run it. How do I get the first character from a char*?

```
int checkLine(char* line){
  
        char l [250];
        strcpy(l,line);
        char first_char = l[0];

        //Check for comment
        if (first_char ==  "#"){
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Should be `first_char == '#'`. But there is no need to copy the string and should check for NULL input. So just `return (line && line[0] == '#')`

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out to someone starting in C that `strcpy()` should be avoided whenever possible. Better to use `strlcpy()` if available, `strncpy()` with extra checks to null terminate, or `sprintf()` for portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just got to change the If statement, instead of using "#" you should use '#', as you're representing a char, not a String. Btw, there is no need to copy your first char into a variable, you can use `if (l[0]=='#')`